# Adobe Flash arabic in code AS3

Tags: list, actionscript-3, flash

I need to put arabic text in as3 code. Specifically when adding items to list component.

I want to add arabic labels to list.

When I press `Ctrl+Enter` - it shows correctly, but when I publish application doesn't show correctly notice that I using flash CC.

Answer (score 0):

When using dynamic textfields, you need to make sure you have Embedded your font.

Select the textfield you are using, then in the property panel, you will see the Embed button. Then select what characters you need or simply select all.

For a list component though, you may not be able to select the textfield. In this case create a temporary textfield, embed the font and select the option to export for actionscript. That will create a font object in your library. Then you can delete the temporary textfield.

Hope that helps!

Comment: that is my code:
list.addItem( { label: "لقد اخترت الرقم1" } );
list.addItem( { label: "لقد اخترت الرقم2" } );
list.addItem( { label: "لقد اخترت الرقم3" } );
list.addItem( { label: "لقد اخترت الرقم4" } );

Arabic doesn't show correctly when I publish my application .

Comment: You need to make sure the font has these characters and the you are embedding them properly. If it's not working at all when using ctrl+Enter, then it means your list component doesn't support right to left text.